# deciphering vim regex

Tags: regex, vim

I'm playing with vim-ruby indent, and there are some pretty complex regexes there:

```
" Regex used for words that, at the start of a line, add a level of indent.
let s:ruby_indent_keywords = '^\s*\zs\<\%(module\|class\|def\|if\|for' .   
      \ '\|while\|until\|else\|elsif\|case\|when\|unless\|begin\|ensure' . 
      \ '\|rescue\):\@!\>' .                                               
      \ '\|\%([=,*/%+-]\|<<\|>>\|:\s\)\s*\zs' .                            
      \    '\<\%(if\|for\|while\|until\|case\|unless\|begin\):\@!\>'
```

With the help of vim documentation I deciphered it to mean:

```
start-of-line <any number of spaces> <start matching> <beginning of a word> /atom
<one of provided keywords> <colon character> <nothing> <end of word> ...
```

I have some doubts:

1. Is it really matching ':'? Doesn't seem to work like that, but I don't see anything about colon being some special character in regexes.
2. why is there `\zs` (start of the match) and no `\ze` (end of the match)?
3. what does \%() do? Is it just some form of grouping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `:\@!` says to match only if there is *not* a colon, if I read it correctly.  I am not familiar with the ruby syntax that this is matching against so this may not be quite correct.  See `:help /\@!` and the surrounding topics for more info on lookarounds.
2. You can have a `\zs` with no `\ze`, it just means that the end of the match is at the end of the regex.  The opposite is also true.
3. `\%(\)` just creates a grouping just as `\(\)` would except that the group is not available as a backreference (like would be used in a `:substitute` command).

Answer (score 1):

1. you can check about matching ':' or any other string by copying the regex and using it to perform a search with `/` on the code you are working. Using `:set incsearch` may help  you to see what is being matched while you type the regex.
2. the `\zs` and `\ze` don't affect what is matched, but instead determine which part of matched text is used in functions as `:s`/`substitute()`. You can check that by performing searches with `/` and `'incsearch'` option set - you can start a search for a string in the text, which will be highlighted, then adding `\zs`and `\ze` will change the highlight on the matched text. There is no need to "close" `\zs`and `\ze`, as one can discard only the start or the end of the match.
3. It is a form of grouping that is not saved in temporary variables for use with `\1`, `\2` or `submatch()`, as stated in `:h \%()`:

   `\%(\)   A pattern enclosed by escaped parentheses.`
   `Just like \(\), but without counting it as a sub-expression.  This`
   `allows using more groups and it's a little bit faster.`